# Boolean field not working - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I want to hide/show fields, depending on a boolean field, in Odoo v9 community

First, I don't know why it isn't working, this is my code:

```
class account_invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    is_export = fields.Boolean(string="¿Es exportación?")
    field_1 = fields.Char ...
    field_2 = fields.Many2one ...
```

Now on my view:

```
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="embarque_form_view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.embarque.form</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name='partner_id' position="after">
                <field name="is_export" class="oe_edit_only" widget="radio"/>
                <field name="puerto_embarque" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"/>
                <field name="puerto_desembarque" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"/>
                <field name="moneda_export" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"/>
                <field name="tara_unit" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"/>
                <field name="weight_unit" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"/>
                <field name="net_weight_unit" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"/>
                <field name="transporte_tipo" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"/>
                <field name="modal_idad" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

The fields are actually hidden, but when I try to click on the boolean field, to activate them, it doesn't work, I mean it just clicks and doesn't becomes 'True' or anything, it remains like if it was unclicked.

I don't know if this is about the attrs I'm adding to every other field, like: `attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '!=', 'True')]}"`

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean field is not working because of ***widget='radio'*** field attribute to hide/show other fields.

Declare *is_export* field with default value *False*

Try with following code:

```
is_export = fields.Boolean(string="¿Es exportación?", default=False)
```

Update your view file with

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="embarque_form_view">
    <field name="name">account.invoice.embarque.form</field>
    <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name='partner_id' position="after">
            <field name="is_export"/>
            <field name="puerto_embarque" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '=', False)]}"/>
            <field name="puerto_desembarque" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '=', False)]}"/>
            <field name="moneda_export" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '=', False)]}"/>
            <field name="tara_unit" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '=', False)]}"/>
            <field name="weight_unit" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '=', False)]}"/>
            <field name="net_weight_unit" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '=', False)]}"/>
            <field name="transporte_tipo" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '=', False)]}"/>
            <field name="modal_idad" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_export', '=', False)]}"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Restart Odoo server and upgrade your module.

Comment: Thank You very much Odedra, but still the same thing :(

Comment: Try with removing *widget='radio'* from *is_export* field.

Comment: I think the widget was the real problem here.  Could you please highlight that in this answer. I will vote up then :-)